# Installing local R package hangs on ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading

Tags: r

I am installing a local R package using `devtools::install()` but the install hangs on the below line (for atleast 30 mins, i've cancelled at this point) and I am struggling to find anything this specific online. Does anyone have any ideas?

`

```
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
```

`

The files are currently on a local branch of a git repo that isn't main, I have seen other posts hinting git can cause issues, however, this problem persists even if I run it outside of a repo.

The full console output with filepaths/names only omitted:

`

```
── R CMD build ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
✔  checking for file '<filepath>/DESCRIPTION' (2.1s)
─  preparing '<library name>': (2.5s)
✔  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information (501ms)
─  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
─  checking for empty or unneeded directories (360ms)
   Omitted 'LazyData' from DESCRIPTION
─  building '<library name>.tar.gz'
   
Running "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-4.2.2/bin/x64/Rcmd.exe" INSTALL "<filepath>\Temp\Rtmp2nSphm/<library name>.tar.gz" --install-tests 
* installing to library '<filepath>/R/win-library/4.2'
* installing *source* package '<library name>' ...
** using staged installation
** R
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
```

`

My file structure:

DESCRIPTION

NAMESPACE

README.md

man/ (populated with .Rd created by roxygen2)

R/     (series of R scripts with comments only outside the function)

Things I have done/checked:

- Check all dependecies are installed.
- Reinstalled devtools.
- Built without vignettes (although I have none).
- Used the "Check" in RStudio which yields no recommendations (this also get's stuck on the "checking whether package can be installed" which I presume is the same issue? I have included this output above.
- My R version isn't the latest but this is controlled centrally by the company, I do not believe this would cause issues as devtools (2.4.5) supports this version.

When using the "Check" option in RStudio I get the below output.

`

```
==> devtools::check(document = FALSE)

══ Building ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Setting env vars:
• CFLAGS    : -Wall -pedantic -fdiagnostics-color=always
• CXXFLAGS  : -Wall -pedantic -fdiagnostics-color=always
• CXX11FLAGS: -Wall -pedantic -fdiagnostics-color=always
• CXX14FLAGS: -Wall -pedantic -fdiagnostics-color=always
• CXX17FLAGS: -Wall -pedantic -fdiagnostics-color=always
• CXX20FLAGS: -Wall -pedantic -fdiagnostics-color=always
── R CMD build ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
✔  checking for file '<filepath>\DESCRIPTION' (1.1s)
─  preparing '<library name>': (1.3s)
✔  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information (791ms)
─  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts (687ms)
─  checking for empty or unneeded directories (698ms)
   Omitted 'LazyData' from DESCRIPTION
─  building '<library name>.tar.gz'
   
══ Checking ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Setting env vars:
• _R_CHECK_CRAN_INCOMING_REMOTE_               : FALSE
• _R_CHECK_CRAN_INCOMING_                      : FALSE
• _R_CHECK_FORCE_SUGGESTS_                     : FALSE
• _R_CHECK_PACKAGES_USED_IGNORE_UNUSED_IMPORTS_: FALSE
• NOT_CRAN                                     : true
── R CMD check ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
─  using log directory '<filepath>/<library name>.Rcheck' (1s)
─  using R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)
─  using platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32 (64-bit)
─  using session charset: UTF-8
─  using options '--no-manual --as-cran' (1.3s)
✔  checking for file '<library name>/DESCRIPTION'
─  checking extension type ... Package
─  this is package '<library name>' version '1.0.0'
─  package encoding: UTF-8 (385ms)
✔  checking package namespace information
✔  checking package dependencies (8.3s)
✔  checking if this is a source package
✔  checking if there is a namespace
✔  checking for executable files (2.3s)
✔  checking for hidden files and directories
✔  checking for portable file names
✔  checking serialization versions
   checking whether package '<library name>' can be installed ...
```

`

Comment: Which library are you trying to install?

Comment: @mhovd it's a locally built library that I created

Comment: Use the base R tools to see if this is an R problem or a `devtools` problem.  From the command line outside of R, `R CMD INSTALL <filepath>` where `<filepath>` is the root directory of the package.  If that works, try `R CMD build <filepath>`, then `R CMD INSTALL pkg.tar.gz`.  Localize the issue.